# moving an article tag to the centre of the page?

Tags: css

I want the article to be centered in order to get in to where i want it. However i do not want in in the centre, i want it a little about an inch to the left and about the same to the top.

what should i do with the following code?

```
article{
    background:white;
    width:650px;
    height:325px;
    border-radius:7px solid;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding:right:10px;
    color:red;
    margin:auto;
    margin-bottom:40px;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'an inch'.

Comment: size, lets say about 20px

Comment: So you effectively want it centered, but then offset to the left and top about 40px;

Answer (score 0):

OK, giving this a shot here... I think this is what you are requesting. basically, I am using a container div to center the content, and then positioning an inner div inside to offset it relative to the centered div.

Codepen sketch here: http://cdpn.io/lthnf

**HTML**

```
<article class='container'>
  <div class='inner'>Content</div>
</article>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  background: #ccc;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 325px;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 650px;
}

.inner {
  background: #efefef;
  position: relative;
  left: -20px;
  top: -20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `position:relative` to your element and then use the  `left` and `top` properties to shift it from the center:

```
article{
    background:black;
    width:650px;
    height:325px;
    border-radius:7px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    color:red;
    margin:auto;
    margin-bottom:40px;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A6CXT/3/embedded/result/)**

Comment: Judging by his answer to my comment above, I think he wants it centered and then offset, not positioned a fixed distance from the top.